# Display entries image files in grid field

Tags: image, grid, files

I've got a grid field called 'images', it has 2 columns in it, a 'files' field, which I've called 'file' and a 'text input' field, which I've called 'caption'. I've got an entry with several images in the 'files' field, and some text in the 'caption' field, but I can't work out how to display these on the front-end, this is what I've got, which doesn't work:

```
{images}
    <img src="{file_url}" alt="{caption}" title="{caption}" />
{/images}
```

I've also tried {file} and {url} in the src but nothing seems to work. If I use the {exp:file:entries} tag that just outputs all my images, and doesn't output the caption anyway.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is not following the user guide's instructions. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html#template-tags

You need to add the prefix for each column.

```
{images}
    <img src="{images:file_url}" alt="{images:caption}" title="{images:caption}" />
{/images}
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry didn't see that. All working now :)